# x-axis name in 2 rows

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have question concerning matlab bar plots.
this is my script:

```
Y = [0.0608 0.0018 
     0.383  0.0146 
     0.2162 0.0106      
     0.1212 0.0067 
     0.2226 0.0771 
     0.1507 0.008 ];
bar(Y,'stack')
grid on
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'200% method','Alt gen method', 'Energy method','PASS 2050','Power bonus method','Exergy method'});
colormap summer
```

Is it possible to set names in x-axis in two rows?
for example to have "200%" in the first row and "method" in the second row lower instead of (200% method) in one row and so on for others.

when I increase front size my names overlap each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [new line in axis tick labels in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560050/new-line-in-axis-tick-labels-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42137-fixxticklabels-automatically-convert-xticklabels-to-multiple-line-format) (fix_xticklabels).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
'1st line \n2nd line'
```

....