# How can I create two-line titles using the LaTeX interpreter?

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, title

I have made a plot in MATLAB and the title is pretty long so I decided to break it into 2 lines. However, it doesn't work when I'm using the LaTeX interpreter.

The title code line looks as follows:

```
title('{Monte-Carlo For Both Linear and Non-Linear Models Using N=300 and An Adjoint Simulation;Frequency = 100Hz $\sigma_{T}=\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$}','Interpreter','latex')
```

How can I make it appear on 2 lines and yet show in LaTeX font?

Comment: Try to embed the lines in the `tabular`environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560050/new-line-in-axis-tick-labels-in-matlab/34135766#34135766

Comment: cant make it work for title, unless im doing something wrong

Comment: @ben: Try with this: `title('\begin{tabular}{c} Monte-Carlo For Both Linear and Non-Linear Models Using $N=300$ \\ and An Adjoint Simulation;Frequency = 100Hz $\sigma_T=\sigma_D=10^{-5}$ \end{tabular}','Interpreter','latex')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the string up into a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) seems to work just fine:

```
title({'Monte-Carlo For Both Linear and Non-Linear Models Using N=300' ...
       'and An Adjoint Simulation; Frequency = 100Hz $\sigma_{T}=\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$'}, ...
      'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

This will end up left-justifying each row. If you need them center-justified, the easiest approach will likely be to use the [`tabular` environment](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables) as suggested by [Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085142/2-lines-title-using-latex-interpreter/47085471?noredirect=1#comment81123326_47085142):

```
title(['\begin{tabular}{c} Monte-Carlo For Both Linear and Non-Linear ' ...
       'Models Using N=300 \\ and An Adjoint Simulation; Frequency = 100Hz ' ...
       '$\sigma_{T}=\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}$ \end{tabular}'], ...
      'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

If you find yourself dealing mainly with math equations and little to no text, `matrix` may be preferable (with `\textrm{...}` to escape text if needed):

```
title('$\matrix{\textrm{Some text} \cr \sigma_{T}=\sigma_{D}=10^{-5}}$', ...
      'Interpreter', 'latex');
```

Comment: only thing is that it align to the left. what if my second line is short and I want it to appear in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this:

```
title({['best solution: ' num2str(1)]... 
[' Cost: ' num2str(20)]})
```

by using {}, you can write your title in several lines.
notice that by using [], you can write in the same line.

[image: result:]