# How to add xlabel ticks from different matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a plot of UTCTime double values from a vector and Altitudes from another vector. I used the function:

```
>> plot(datenum(cellstr(UTCTime),string('yyyymmddHHMMSS')),Altitudes );
```

And it works fine. Well, now I have another two vectors on Longitudes and Latitudes ( same size of UTCTime vector ).
How can I put on ticks the corrispondent value of Latitudes and Longitudes at specific UTCTime ?

[image]

UTCTime : 2242x1 double

Latitudes: 2242x1 double

Longitudes: 2242x1 double

Comment: Hi, could you share the code for `UTCTime`, `Longitudes` and `Latitudes` ?

Comment: They are vectors UTCTime : 2242x1 double, Latitudes: 2242x1 double, Longitudes: 2242x1 double. For example UTCTime(1) = 7.056.... Latitudes(1) = 60.0 Longitudes(1) = -180.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line in axis tick labels in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560050/new-line-in-axis-tick-labels-in-matlab)

Comment: Note especially the newer, higher-voted answer to the duplicate question, which is a much tidier workaround that should suit this version of the problem well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [xticks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html) and [xticklabels](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html) commands, you can specify the values and labels for the x-axis.

For example, if you wanted to have tick marks every 10 degrees Lat, you could say this:

```
xticks_mat = max(latitude):-10:min(latitude);
xticks(xticks_mat);
```

You then could use xticklabels to specify what your x-axis labels would say at each tick mark.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not setting the xticks because with `plot(UTCTime, Altitude)` it already works. I need to show latitudes and longitudes label values like the picture in the question

Comment: If you want to add a new label, I would suggest trying to create a new [axis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html). There can be one label per axis, so if I am understanding you correctly, you will need 3 axes to display all the data you want to. You will also probably need to set the position of these axes using the [set](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html?searchHighlight=set&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) command to a graphical position under the first UTC axis.